# user are authorized to access page after login

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

hi how can i write a code in my system, that is

1) User 1 : add, delete, update, view
2) user 2: update only
3) user 3 : view only

i using vb.net and access database. there are some of my code

```
Dim strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\MIS\LabSystem\LabTestSystem\LabSystemDB.mdb"
 Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)

    conn.Open()
    'Enter default login details username and password
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from Login where username='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and password='" & TextBox2.Text & "'", conn)
    dt.Clear()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Session("username") = TextBox1.Text
        Response.Redirect("Main.aspx")

    Else
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        Label1.Text = "Incorrect value: Invalid login or password."
        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    End If
```

Comment: Unless this is a very small private site, MS Access is not a good choice of database. No matter what kind of site, there is no point in creating user roles when you are not sanitizing your input. MS Access is much less vulnerable to SQL injection than other databases, but it is not immune. I suggest you switch immediately to parameters, before the whole thing gets unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

From taking a look at the code you have provided, I assume this is an asp.net web application you are working on?

To limit the site users to do a fixed scope of operations, you will need to implement a role based authorization mechanism in your site. User 1 will be in role 1, where the users in role 1 can add, update, delete and view. Users in role 2 can only update, and users in role 3 can only view.

Take a look at the following links to get an idea on how to implement a role provider for your site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74(v=vs.100).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281573/ASP-NET-Membership-and-Role-Provider